# The free completion of a category under sifted colimits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, functors, formal-completions

The free completion of a category under sifted colimit is denoted by $$Sind \ \cal K.$$ If $\cal K$ has sifted colimits we have the functor as in the snippet below:$$\text{colim}:Sind\ \cal K\to K.$$

My question is easy: how formally (technically) look the category $Sind\ \cal K$ and the functor $\text{colim}$?

I have some intuition which is, however, not precise.

[image]

Comment: If you are quoting multiple paragraphs of text, you should be citing where it comes from.

Comment: @DerekElkins It is this paper: Algebra and local presentability: how algebraic are they?, J Rosický with J. Adámek, Tbilisi Math. Jour. 10 (2017), 279-295

Answer (score 2):

You can see this paper

[Adamek, Rosicky, Vitale, *What are sifted colimits? (2010)](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/Adamek-et-al.pdf)

which states a slogan (and conditions for theorem) that:

> the free completion of $\mathcal C$ under sifted colimits is the free completion of $Ind\ \mathcal C$ under reflexive coequalizers.

The category $Ind \mathcal\ C$ of Ind-objects you may already know, which can be constructed for example as the full subcategory of presheaves on $\mathcal C$ of objects which are colimits of representables (cf. [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object#as_filtered_colimits_of_representable_presheaves)).

As for the completion under reflexive coequalizers, this is mentioned in:

[Adamek, Rosicky; *On sifted colimits and generalized varieties* (2001)](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.69.7612&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

which in turn points to

[Bunge, Carboni; *The symmetric topos* (1995)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82079823.pdf)

There it deals with with the construction of completion under equaliers, mentions this is equivalent to completion under coreflexive equalizers, and also mentions the dual case of coequalizers.

I won't dig any further, but this is probably enough information to get to a formal definition of $Sind \mathcal\ C$.